# Is there any way to replace --privileged with --security-opt and --cap-add in docker?

Tags: linux, docker, containers, cgroups, linux-capabilities

I want to run a specific container(k3s) need privileged mode in a windows docker with(lcow feature), but windows do not support --privileged.
so Is there any way to replace it with --security-opt and --cap-add?

Comment: The `docker run` documentation has a [list of capabilities](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities); but note that these are Linux capabilities and this might not work in a Windows container.

Comment: @DavidMaze, yes I want to run a linux container in windows host(which called LCOW), but this setting not allow --privileged, so I want figure out a way to replace it.